# Unreal Engine: How to get FollowCamera in my character.cpp

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

My question is show do I go to get the FollowCamera in my character.cpp if I generated a third person blueprint project?

I'm following this tutorial to set up a pick up/inventory system  in C++: https://youtu.be/BQ6Eu3QM7Lg?t=1681

All the while I'm using a blueprint project.

Initially my blueprint project didn't have a character class in C++. So I generated a MyCharacter.cpp and header file to write my c++ code and to complement my blueprint. When I compare his character class with mine, mine is empty, how can I get the FollowCamera into my class? Thank you guys, I'm really new to unreal engine and I'm not enjoying my experience with it.

Comment: When you created your MyCharacter.cpp class, did you make it a child of the existing Character class?

Comment: How can I do this @Fritz ?